# Raycast to find point that intersects the z-axis at zero

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to make a raycast that triggers when it intersects zero on the z-axis, rather than waiting to hit an object?

I have an orthographic camera at `(0, 0, -40)`, and facing directly towards the origin. I want to send a raycast from the center of each edge of the camera's viewport to find the (x, y) points where they intersect the z-axis at zero.

Comment: you should probably just use math but if you want to raycast why not just make a large plane in its own scene and raycast against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an orthographic camera, the edges of the frustum are parallel like a box. Looking straight down the Z-axis, you can get the x,y values easily with:

**x:** `camera.left` or `camera.right`

**y:** `camera.top` or `camera.bottom`

They don't diverge at all, since ortho cams don't have perspective, so they'll also cross the Z-plane at the position of the camera's edges.